# Set up two (2) IP addresses on the same network card?

Tags: windows-xp, ip-address, network-adapter, subnet

I think it is possible to set up 2 IP addresses and subnet masks on one NIC in Windows XP.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7):

Having more than 2 IP addresses is called [Multihoming](http://napps.networkworld.com/columnists/2004/110104gearhead.html).
Most Multihoming solutions require giving up DHCP addressing in favor of static ones.

Actually, there is a way to multihome a network interface card (NIC) under XP and use both DHCP and multiple static IP addresses. Here's how, taken from [Eccentricities of Windows networking](http://napps.networkworld.com/columnists/2004/110104gearhead.html) :

1. Use regedit to navigate to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Class\NetTrans`
2. Under these subkeys you'll find all
   of the NICs in your PC listed by
   their COM Class Identifiers
   otherwise known as Globally Unique
   Identifiers (GUID). For
   example:
   `{A8BF419B-8185-4396-B87A-2B6345BBC8E3}`
   Be careful to correctly identify
   which NIC the entry refers to -
   you'll find multiple GUIDs listed
   under each NIC in the registry.
3. Find the key `IPAddress` and double
   click on it. In the Edit
   Multi-String dialog that appears,
   enter in the value of each of the
   static IP addresses you want to
   assign to the NIC, one value per
   line. Note that the first value must
   be "0.0.0.0".
4. Now find the `SubnetMask` key and
   edit it exactly the same way you did
   the "IPAddress" key, again making
   sure the first value is "0.0.0.0".
5. Reboot.

Comment: Any clue how to do this for Windows 7?  I created these entries in the registry (they aren't present by default, which makes me think they may have removed this ability), but still couldn't access the other network after disabling and re-enabling the interface.

Comment: Does this help : [How to Configure a Multihomed Server](http://www.ehow.com/how_6951540_configure-multihomed-server.html).

Comment: Sorry, no.  That article talks about a computer with two NICs, but I was looking for assigning two IP address to one NIC, like your original answer.  I've used that procedure often on our XP computers with only one NIC, and today I tried to use it on a Windows 7 machine, only to find it unsuccessful.

Comment: @sskuce: Understood. How about the procedure described in [this article](http://www.itsyourip.com/networking/how-to-add-multiple-ip-address-in-windows-2000xp2003/).

Comment: We want to have one address assigned by DHCP, and the other statically assigned.  The procedure from "Eccentricities of Windows Networking" allows this for XP machines, but not for Windows 7.  The itsyourip article you just linked is only good for two or more static IPs, unfortunately.  Thanks though!

Comment: Well, apparently Microsoft disabled this type of configuration in Windows 7. Windows has become too intelligent for us mortals.

Answer (score 6):

I usually do this with netsh as it's easy to replicate.

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 10.0.10.20 255.255.255.0 10.0.10.1 1
netsh interface ip add address "Local Area Connection" 192.168.1.20 255.255.255.0
```

Now you'll want to configure DNS also, I presume.

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 10.0.10.1
netsh interface ip add dns "Local Area Connection" 192.168.1.140
```

I'll then save these commands to a .cmd file and save that in my source code repository (or other backed up location) for posterity.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, although both IP's have to be static.

1. Control Panel -> Network Connections
2. Right click the NIC -> Properties
3. TCP/IP->Properties
4. Click Advanced
5. Under IP Addresses click Add.

Comment: actually there is a way to make this work with DHCP (for the first address; the second address must be static).  see harrymc's answer.

Comment: i did it and i can successfully ping myself on that new IP address, but other machines cannot ping me on new IP address?

Comment: you still have to follow the rules of subnetting :-)

Answer (score 2):

Searched Microsoft for "second ip address windows xp" it was the 5th link.

Read though you'll see it in there.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457118.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It does not work with dhcp but with static ips you can set it by going to

Network card properties.
Internet Protocol(TCP/IP) properties.
Click advanced

In this screen you can add as much ip's and gatways as you want.

Comment: actually there is a way to make this work with DHCP (for the first address; the second address must be static).  see harrymc's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Registry Key details here apply to Windows 98; different info applies to XP - go to the [Eccentricities of Windows Networking](http://www.networkworld.com/columnists/2004/110104gearhead.html) site for the right info.