# Windows 2k/xp and lan configuration with gateway different from subnet

Tags: networking, windows-xp

I have this lan configuration

```
TESTLAN=10.2.0.0/24
ROUTERLAN=192.168.0.0/24
```

With linux machines no problem,using dhcp and even with testlan addresses
they get the routerlan router(192.168.0.1) and can connect and ping all lan's
I have problems with XP and windows machines,they are virtual machines(as linux)
and they cannot ping the routerlan and of course cannot ping internet.
I have tried dhcp and static configuration with those params

```
ipaddr=10.2.0.11
netmask=255.255.255.0
gateway=192.168.0.1
dns=192.168.0.1
```

Of course i have tried to add route manually,but no success

```
route add net 192.168.0.1 mask 255.255.255.0 10.2.0.11 metric 20
```

What's wrong?
I have tried XP

Comment: If you want to use a gateway in 192.168.0.x, then you need an IP address in that subnet. Assign an additional IP (in the 192.168.0.x subnet) to that XP machine's NIC.

Comment: Why on linux can i use a gateway different of subnet and on xp not?Is windows so limited?Seem impossible

Comment: Windows isn't limited; you can't do it on Linux either.  See [Does the gateway have to be on the subnet?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98344/does-the-gateway-have-to-be-on-the-subnet).   If the gateway isn't part of a network you belong to, there's no way for it to find the gateway to leave said network.

Comment: Sure right,i was confused first,because linux can associate different ip to dev and so i think linux can get the gateway.

Comment: If you  want to add your comment as answer i can vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a gateway in 192.168.0.x, then you need an IP address in that subnet. Assign an additional IP (in the 192.168.0.x subnet) to that XP machine's NIC.

For info on accomplishing that, check out this other SU question/answers: [Set up two (2) IP addresses on the same network card?](https://superuser.com/questions/73522/set-up-two-2-ip-addresses-on-the-same-network-card)